# output the items that showed up 2 times and more

Tags: bash, shell, awk, bash-scripting

How can I select the ips that showed up 4 times or more , for example here?

the input file is

```
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.31
192.168.101.2
192.168.1.31
192.168.11.02
192.168.1.31
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.31
192.168.21.31
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.31
```

and then I'd like to get this output:

```
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.31
```

USING AWK is preferred

thank you all! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you combine Nicole Hamilton's answer and `gawk` you get (for lines that appear 4 times or more):

```
sort iplist.txt | uniq -c | gawk '$1>=4{print $2}'
```

For exactly four times do :

```
sort iplist.txt | uniq -c | gawk '$1==4{print $2}'
```

Change the `4` to whichever number you are interested in.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume the list in a file named `iplist.txt`.  Try this:

```
sort iplist.txt | uniq -d
```

Here's what it looks like when you run it.  I've deliberately added a 3rd occurrence of the IP address `192.168.1.28` so you can see that only the lines that occur 2 *or more* times get listed in the output, with each duplicated line shown just once.

```
bash-4.1$ cat iplist.txt
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.31
192.168.101.2
192.168.11.02
192.168.1.31
192.168.21.31
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.28
bash-4.1$ sort iplist.txt | uniq -d
192.168.1.28
192.168.1.31
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: is this really can select items that occur 3 times or more also?

Comment: Yes, any line that appears more than once will listed once.

Comment: no i want to clarify that show items whome appears more than x times not just onece

Comment: You many need to rewrite your question to clarify what it is you want.  You asked about lines that appear "2 times and more" and your example shows printing the two IP addresses that appeared exactly twice.  My proposed solution gives that output on your sample input.  And if you added 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc., occurrences of those same duplicated IP addresses, the output would be the same.

Comment: I've edited my example to show what happens if a given entry appears 3 times, not just twice.

Comment: what about appearing 5 times or more?(i've edit the question)thank you for your time :)

Comment: Then use `uniq -c` to get a count of the number of occurrences of each value then select the lines you want.  `awk` would be perfect for that but I'll leave it to write that.

Answer (score 2):

For 4 times or more try:

```
awk '++A[$1]==4' file
```